# Error 400 Bad Request al consumir API Serverless

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda, amazon

Tengo unas apis subidas a AWS el cual intento consumirlas en el front o algun cliente para las apis y estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:
400 ERROR - The request could not be satisfied. Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront

Intente ponerle los siguientes headers en el response de los apis y aun asi sigue sin funcionar.

```
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
          },
```

Tambien intente habilitar cors en API Gateway pero tampoco funciono.

Comment: el problema esta en los headers que mandas en la peticion HTTP, escribe el codigo de la consulta para intentar replicarlo y asi poder ayudarte, otra opcion es que intentes acceder desde el navegador y ver si te responde algun json, si te reponde entonces el problema esta en codigo del frontend (cliente)

Comment: No solo en el front, tambien en Thunder Client (que sirve para hacer consultas a apis) o incluso en google(Los endpoints gets).

Comment: No indicas cómo has subido las APIs (qué lenguaje usas, qué frameworks dentro de ese lenguaje -- P.E.: Python con fastAPI --. Tampoco indicas si usas o no API Gateway ni si estás usando AWS Lambda u otro sistema -- como EC2 -- para alojar las APIs, así que la pregunta en sí no hay por donde cogerla. Las etiquetas de la pregunta solo sirven para ayudar a clasificar las preguntas, pero todo debe estar bien explicado en la pregunta ... no sería la primera pregunta que tiene mal los tags ...